# Insert new row in Table

Tags: jquery

I have a problem where the `:eq()` does not accept the counter, `n`, to insert values to a new column to the table in the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $tablerow = $('table.table').find('tr');
    count = 0;

    $tablerow.each(function(index, value){
        count += 1;
        var $listitem = $(this);
        n = parseInt($listitem.index());
        var $newRow = $("<td>" + n + "</td>");
        $("table.table tr:eq(n)").append($newRow);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tr><td>First row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>second row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>third row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fourth row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fifth row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sixth row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>seventh row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>eighth row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need find. You just want an array of the TR's. `$('.table tr')` will grab those. But if you have more than one table with that class, beware (same goes for find mind you). ;-)

Comment: what do you want? Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written as-is, you're doing nothing more than writing a literal character, 'n', into `.eq()` method. Try this:

```
$("table.table tr:eq(" + n + ")").append($newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try using it like previous line where you used qoutes
`$("table.table tr:eq(" + n + ")").append($newRow);`

Answer (score 0):

No need to index `this` inside `$.each` since as your arguments show the first one is index.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
    var $tablerow = $('table.table tr');

    $tablerow.each(function(index,element){
       /* "this" is current row*/
         $(this).append("<td>" + index+1 + "</td>" )
    });
});
```

Comment: Code is shorter, but result is different from what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 var $newRow = $("<td>" + n + "</td>");
 $("table.table tr:eq(n)").append($newRow);`
```

with

```
var $newRow = $("<td>" + (n+1) + "</td>");
$("table.table tr:eq(" + n + ")").append($newRow);
```

This will work